# How to print two lines from grep into one line with bash script

Tags: bash, grep, echo, mediainfo

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have a directory with multiple video files in it, I want to list all the files and in the same line add the duration and size of the file , using mediainfo (nothing else is available).

Mediainfo's output would be something like:

```
General
Format      : 
File Size   : 335 MiB
Duration    : 28mn 24s
```

I want to get the following data in a file:
filename : 335 MiB : 28mn 24s
So I can check if there are duplicates of the file...

Therefore I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
         for i in $( ls /mnt/storage/kids/* ); do
                     echo -n item: $i ":"
                     mediainfo $i |grep -A 1 "File size"
                     done
```

with echo n I get the following line in the same line as item: $i and with grep -A 1 I get both file size and duration but duration goes into a second line isntead of the same as the file name and file size.
I would also like to get rid of file name and duration headers.

Any idea?

Comment: Don't do `for i in $(ls)`. Use the glob directly: `for i in /mnt/storage/kids/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use `for i in $(ls)`, this is buggy. If you want to loop over files use `for i in /mnt/storage/kids/*` directly.
- Avoid `echo -n` in favor of `printf`, which is portable.

Try this:

```
for i in /mnt/storage/kids/* ; do
    printf 'item: %s: ' "$i"
    mediainfo "$i" | sed -e '/File Size/,/Duration/{s/.*: //p;};d' | sed -e '$!N;s/\n/: /'
done
```

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the double line, change your code into:

```
echo -n item: $i ":" $(mediainfo $i |grep -A 1 "File size")
```

To get rid of the headers, you can use awk:

```
$ echo -e 'Filename : BOO\nSize : BAA' | awk -F: '{print $2}'
 BOO
 BAA
```

Comment: Is the `-n` still necessary? I think not. The `-n` was there when OP didn't want a newline right after printing ":"